# Close window with Catel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

I'm using [Catel](http://www.catelproject.com/) as my MVVM framework to develop a WPF application.

I open my window via the UIVisualizerService, provided by Catel, like this:

```
this.uiVisualizerService.ShowDialog(new ViewModel);
```

This works perfectly. 
The problem is that I can't close my window with, like said on the Catel website

```
this.CloseViewModel(true);
```

When I click the cancel button, the command is executed, but nothing happens.

**More info:**

My window code-behind class:

```
public partial class Window : Window
{
    public Window()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

My Cancel button:

```
<Button Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" />
```

My command method in my viewmodel:

```
 private void CancelCommandExecuted()
    {
        this.CloseViewModel(true);
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the DataWindow or a custom implementation?

Comment: None, do I have to? Can I use this with the standard WPF window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/MVVM+behaviors#MVVMbehaviors-WindowBehavior

Now I have a normal WPF window that I can close with Catel.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in the latest nightly build.

For more information about the issue:
https://catelproject.atlassian.net/browse/CTL-158

For more information about getting the latest nightly build:
https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Getting+prerelease+%28beta%29+versions+via+NuGet

Comment: This doesn't work in combination with the standard/default WPF window. With the nightly build, I can close my window if it derives from 'DataWindow', but not if it derives from 'Window'.

Comment: If it is a regular / standard WPF window, then how is it possible that it is even loaded via the VM. The window should contain a WindowLogic or WindowLogicBehavior to behave like a Catel window.

Comment: Ok, so it is not possible? Even if I open the window with the `UIVisualizerService` that is provided (like I said in my start post)?

Comment: No, the reason is that it finds the window via a naming convention from MySpecialViewModel => MySpecialWindow. However, closing the view based on the VM.Closed event is implemented in the LogicBase. You will need to add this to your window. If you don't want to use the DataWindow, read this: https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Using+a+custom+window